# Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (404, 13)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = keras.datasets.boston_housing

(x_train , y_train) , (x_test , y_test) = data.load_data()

model = keras.Sequential([

    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28 , 28 )),

    keras.layers.Dense(128 , activation="relu"),

    keras.layers.Dense(10 , activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam" , loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy" , metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x_train , y_train ,epochs=5 )

test_loss , test_acc = model.evaluate(x_test , y_test)

print("tested acc: ", test_acc)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Flatten` layer is to turn 3D+ tensors into 2D. I'm guessing this model was designed for the Binary MNIST, which has a different input shape, and you tried using it on another dataset. The Boston Housing Dataset already has 2D input so it doesn't make sense here. You could make this run by changing the input shape, but it wouldn't make sense:

```
keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(13,)),
```

All you have to do is remove it and it will run fine. Then you'll have to change your loss function, your metrics, and your final activation function because you're dealing with a regression problem. Final, corrected code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = keras.datasets.boston_housing

(x_train , y_train) , (x_test , y_test) = data.load_data()

model = keras.Sequential([

    keras.layers.Dense(128 , activation="relu"),

    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam" , loss="mae")

model.fit(x_train , y_train ,epochs=5 )

test_loss = model.evaluate(x_test , y_test)

print("test loss: ", test_loss)
```

```
 32/102 [========>.....................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.9563
102/102 [==============================] - 0s 682us/sample - loss: 6.7218

test loss:  6.721758244084377
```

Comment: I edited a few things, feel free to try it again now

Answer (score 0):

`Flatten` is used to make 2d data like image flat, so basically you convert 2d list in 1d list, so you should change `Flatten` to `Input`.

Second mistake is declaring input shape.

```py
input_shape=(28 , 28 )
```

You declared `28x28`, but I presume you wanted to have 28 samples with 28 features. And this is constant. To do it properly, you define input shape to be flexible, it will match any amount of samples in training and prediction. All you need to do i pass how many features one sample has

```py
input_shape=(28, )
```

This is how it should look like

```py
model = keras.Sequential([

    keras.layers.Input(input_shape=(28, )),

    keras.layers.Dense(128 , activation="relu"),

    keras.layers.Dense(10 , activation="softmax")
])
```